# Can module loading be globally disabled on modern Linux kernels?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Once upon a time (before kernel 2.6.25), one could use `/proc/sys/kernel/cap-bound` to drop `CAP_SYS_MODULE` system-wide, and be assured that the set of code that was presently loaded into kernel space was all there would ever be, absent exploits or rebooting.

Then it was decided that `CAP_NET_ADMIN` would be allowed to load kernel modules even without `CAP_SYS_MODULE`(!), and the value of `CAP_SYS_MODULE` came to a close -- grepping through a modern kernel, I find no runtime checks for `CAP_SYS_MODULE` to still exist.

What's the modern replacement?

Answer (score 2):

Kees Cook implemented a sysctl to fill this need in early 2009. As documented in [Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt):

> `modules_disabled`:
>
> A toggle value indicating if modules are allowed to be loaded
>   in an otherwise modular kernel.  This toggle defaults to off
>   (`0`), but can be set true (`1`).  Once true, modules can be
>   neither loaded nor unloaded, and the toggle cannot be set back
>   to false.  Generally used with the "kexec_load_disabled" toggle.

---

As mentioned, this should be used with `kexec_load_disabled` if the goal is to control which code is active in kernelspace:

> `kexec_load_disabled`:
>
> A toggle indicating if the kexec_load syscall has been disabled. This
>   value defaults to `0` (false: kexec_load enabled), but can be set to `1`
>   (true: kexec_load disabled). Once true, kexec can no longer be used, and
>   the toggle cannot be set back to false. This allows a kexec image to be
>   loaded before disabling the syscall, allowing a system to set up (and
>   later use) an image without it being altered. Generally used together
>   with the "modules_disabled" sysctl.